# pushing multiple unrelated commits to remote git repo

Tags: git, gerrit

I have a situation where I am working on two different projects on a particular branch. I have finished project "A", committed the change, and pushed the change up to the remote. This change "A" is currently under review so it hasn't been merged yet to the branch. Meanwhile I have started working on an unrelated change for another project in the same branch, call this change "B". I have finished coding this change as well and I'm ready to commit and push this. But I'm not sure how this should be done since change "A" hasn't been merged yet. How can I push these two changes "A" and "B" as separate changes that don't depend on each other?

Comment: I have edited my answer. The step `git checkout parent_commit` where parent_commit = the commit hash checks out the state of the repo at that commit, and the following `git checkout -b commitB` creates the new branch from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to identify the commit that will be the common parent of Change A and B. As you have described it, this is the parent of commit A. Use `git log` to find the hash for the commit before A. Note that you can just type the first few letters/numbers of the commit hash. Let's pretend it is "parent_commit"

Now checkout this commit, which we are going to use as the head of a new branch for Change B.

```
git checkout parent_commit
```

Next create a new branch from it, where we will commit the B changes.

```
git checkout -b changeB
```

Finally, use `git add` and `git commit` to commit your Change B on this new branch. When done, do a `git push` to push your commit B from your new branch that is independent of change A. Alternatively, if you have already committed Change B, then use `git cherry-pick commitB` then `git pull`.

Now you will have your original branch with A, and a new branch with B, sharing the history up to the parent of A.

Closing remark: if you had already committed B and made a branch for it (and had it checked out) you could have done the rebase one-liner mentioned in the other answer:

```
git rebase --onto master commit_A_sha
```

Comment: i sort of understand what you're saying, but can you describe how I can create a new branch "common_parent" by giving it the commit ID of the common parent. I would need to do this because my change "A" is already committed.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the same result as Shelhamer's response; but you can use `git rebase --onto` to achieve the same result in a single command. Locate the SHA id of the 'old' parent (A in your example), and the SHA id of the new parent (say *master*). Then assuming you have got the branch in question (B) checked out, run:

```
git rebase --onto <new parent> <old parent>
```

This will essentially 'pick-up' everything on branch B from A onwards and will move it so it's based off the master. Then just `git push` as normal.